# OpenCV GTK+2.x error - "Unspecified error (The function is not implemented...)"

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, makefile

I had installed OpenCV following these steps. After trying to compile one example, I got this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /home/nick/.Apps/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 516
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/nick/.Apps/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:516: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(threadTest)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pthread")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "/home/nick/ClionProjects/threadTest")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(threadTest ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries( threadTest ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Just read the error message? It states: _The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with [..] GTK+ 2.x [..] support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script_ If you are not using Ubuntu or Debian, try to figure out how the GTK 2.0 developer package is called and install it together with pkg-config.

Comment: i had installed libgtk2.0-dev and it doesn't help :(

Comment: Does CMke find it? Have a look in the output. Maybe you have to path the path to Gtk to CMake.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First check whether libgtk2.0-dev is installed properly. If you have installed [aptitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_%28software%29) package manager, run the following:

```
sudo aptitude search libgtk2.0-dev
```

It should return like this:

```
i  libgtk2.0-dev              - development files for the GTK+ library
p  libgtk2.0-dev:i386         - development files for the GTK+ library
```

You need to build the files once again. Locate your OpenCV folder. Create a new folder and name it *Release*. Enter into this folder. For example,

```
cd /home/user_name/OpenCv
mkdir Release
cd Release
```

Now build using CMake with following command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..
```

Remember to put `WITH_GTK=ON` during CMake.

After this step, enter the command,

```
make
sudo make install
```

This should resolve your problem. If you have broken dependencies for libgtk2.0-dev, then install a fresh copy of libgtk2.0-dev using aptitude.

```
sudo aptitude install libgtk2.0-dev
```

Comment: Thanks. Basically, to solve the problem I had to recompile and install OpenCV with GTK, **WITH_GTK=ON**.

Comment: Doesn't work on 2017. Even after doing all those steps, I still get the gtk error and can't do cv2.imshow.

Comment: @Thomio what is the command line you put to solve the problem?

Comment: if the problem with just GTK. Do i need to compile with openGL??

Comment: This worked. I have been struggling so hard for resolving this issue, finally this solution worked

Answer (score 16):

If you installed OpenCV using the opencv-python pip package, be aware of the following note, taken from *[opencv-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python)*:

> **IMPORTANT NOTE** 
> macOS and Linux wheels have currently some limitations:

> - video related functionality is not supported (not compiled with FFmpeg)

- for example `cv2.imshow()` will not work (not compiled with GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support)

Also note that to install from another source, first you must remove the opencv-python package.

To install OpenCV in Ubuntu, I followed this guide, and it worked perfectly fine: *[Ubuntu 16.04: How to install OpenCV](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/)*

Answer (score 9):

In order to improve [Nic Szer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43526714/1472337) I want to explain how to fix this error on macOS in three simple steps.

1. Remove installed OpenCV version to avoid messing up later

   ```
   pip3 uninstall opencv-python
   ```
2. Lower your Python version to 3.5 (the current version, 3.6, has problems with [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) which we will use to install OpenCV)

   ```
   conda install python=3.5
   ```
3. Finally, use Conda to install a working version of OpenCV

   ```
   conda install -c menpo opencv3
   ```

And then voilà: OpenCV will start working on your macOS ([macOS v10.12.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra) (Sierra)).

Comment: Yeah you could also just edit my answer instead of selfishly seeking points.

Answer (score 7):

For Windows, just uninstall the OpenCV package:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

And reinstall:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: was gonna write this :)

Comment: small addition: in my case, i was uninstall `opencv-python-headless` yet

Answer (score 5):

In case what is mentioned in previous answers doesn't work, try:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

for Python 2, or

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

for Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

I have had to deal with this issue a couple of times, and this is what has worked consistently thus far:

```
conda remove opencv
conda install -c menpo opencv
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score 3):

For me (Arch Linux, Anaconda with Python 3.6), installing from the suggested channels `menpo` or `loopbio` did not change anything. My solution was to

1. install pkg-config (`sudo pacman -Syu pkg-config`),
2. remove opencv from the environment (`conda remove opencv`) and
3. re-install opencv from the conda-forge channel (`conda install -c conda-forge opencv`)

`conda list` now returns `opencv 3.3.0 py36_blas_openblas_203 [blas_openblas] conda-forge`and all windows launched using cv2 are working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) LTS (Xenial Xerus) environment with [GTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK) 3 preinstalled.

I got the same error for [Caffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffe_(software)) build (master branch),
Try the following steps, may be it should work for you.

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
cmake .. (WITH_GTK=ON and other settings),
make
```

And bingo, the error was gone... in my Python Caffe code

Please note:

The CMake configuration should reflect GTK+ 3.x instead of GTK+ 2.x:

```
       GUI:
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 3.x:                    YES (ver 3.18.9)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.48.2)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
```

Comment: In the official opencv installation guide (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) they still link to libgtk2.0-dev. If your application uses Gtk3, then you should replace by libgtk-3-dev, as suggested by @SeCp

Answer (score 2):

I have the solved using [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) 3 installing on [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus).

I have used the [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm) editor for my Python code.

I am using the Python 3.6 version.

I solved the issue using these processes.

IDEA: we need to install the package opencv-contrib-python package from PyCharm.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After installing OpenCV using vcpkg on Ubuntu, there is a known issue with vcpkg where you'll end up with the exact same error message as the top of this post with no access to highgui:

> OpenCV(4.3.0) Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. 
> If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, 
> file .../vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/src/4.3.0-0c6047baf6.clean/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 634 
> Caught exception: OpenCV(4.3.0) .../vcpkg/buildtrees/opencv4/src/4.3.0-0c6047baf6.clean/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:634: 
> error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. 
>
> If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvNamedWindow'

The problem is vcpkg passes in the build option `-DWITH_GTK=OFF` when building OpenCV.  The open issue:  https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/12621

The workaround is the following:

- edit the file `vcpkg/ports/opencv4/portfile.cmake`
- find the line that says `-DWITH_GTK=OFF` and change it to say `-DWITH_GTK=ON`
- run `./vcpkg remove opencv4`
- run `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config`
- reinstall OpenCV with `./vcpkg install opencv4` or whichever vcpkg command you used

Answer (score 2):

My issue was solved after installing opencv-contrib-python:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed my issue using this,try it

```
pip install opencv-python-headless==4.5.3.56 
pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.5.3.56
pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and fixed it by simply [reinstalling opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation).

There is no need to uninstall it first.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several of the previous answers the one that worked for me in ubuntu is mentioned in the following steps:

1. Firstly, remove the current *opencv* package that is installed in your system by typing in the following command in the terminal `conda remove opencv`.
2. If your Python version is 3.6 or above then change it into the stable version which can be done by typing in `conda install python=3.5`.
3. Later on, install the opencv package again by giving the following input in terminal `conda install -c menpo opencv3`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it has been resolved after uninstalling opencv-python and doing a fresh install.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. It worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install cmake cmake-curses-gui libgtk2.0-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

reinstalling and installing with the above command solved my issue but just after closing all instances of pyhton and anaconda because apparently a cache version of the library was being kept in my system.

Hence, uninstall opencv (try with pip and conda), close the IDE and reboot it, check if you can import opencv. If you still can import it, try to run the code:

```
help(cv2)
```

and check where the files are stored and delete that folder.
Repeat the process untill you are sure it is uninstalled so you can reinstall opencv full package (option 2 - see https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ )

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it has been resolved after uninstalling opencv-python version 4 and then installing the OpenCV version 3.

**pip install opencv-python==3.4.9.33**

Answer (score 0):

Check if libgtk2.0-dev and is pkg-config installed. Otherwise:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config
```

Then switch to your opencv build directory and rebuild everything:

```
cmake ../opencv-4.x
cmake --build .
sudo make install
```

Please see: [OpenCV's namedWindow is not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72751473/opencvs-namedwindow-is-not-implemented)
and
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed this issue by replacing

```
cvDestroyWindow("showImage");
```

by

```
cvDestroyWindow("ShowImage");
```