# Install opencv-python under python3 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use opencv under python 3 in Ubunto 14.04. I plan to use the PyCharm IDE to develop my program.

Inside PyCharm I choose, I set:

**File/Settings/Project:HelloWorld/Project Interpreter/3.4.3(/usr/bin/python3.4)**

Python 3.4.3 is the default version of python in Ubunto 14.04.

Then I try to add **opencv-python** package:

**File/Settings/Project:HelloWorld/Project Interpreter/+** (where you add the package)

and the system gives me this error:

```
 Executed command:

 pip install opencv-python 


 Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you   
 use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/usr/bin/python3.4'.

 DEPRECATION: --no-install, --no-download, --build, and --no-clean are   deprecated.  See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.
 Downloading/unpacking opencv-python
 Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement opencv-python
 Cleaning up...
 No distributions at all found for opencv-python
 Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

the error is the same when I run the command from terminal. I believe the problem is related to installing opencv under python3 but I am not sure I know if I can fix it. Please let me know your opinion.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The fix is to update your pip and try again. This worked for me.

So, first:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

after that:

`pip install opencv-python`

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not use install opencv-python, this is not the official opencv package. 
Please, see:
[**SOLVED** How to include libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config in cmake when installing openCV on Ubuntu 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843316/solved-how-to-include-libgtk2-0-dev-and-pkg-config-in-cmake-when-installing?noredirect=1#comment72858371_42843316)

If you want to install opencv, you can follow this [website](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/), that worked for me. You might need to apapt some parts (mainly version numbers, and paths during the cmake process).

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar issue in the windows and pip upgrade worked for me,

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and install using below command,

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from querying pip (using `pip search opencv`) there is no package called `opencv-python` I think the one you're looking for is `pyopencv`.

[this issue appears to be almost identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215102/installing-opencv-for-python-on-ubuntu-getting-importerror-no-module-named-cv2)

Comment: I could solve the problem following this: http://cyaninfinite.com/tutorials/installing-opencv-in-ubuntu-for-python-3/. No, I have another problem (seems some libraries are missing). Here is the error: `OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config,`.

Comment: (I don't mean this to sound like I'm being sarcastic) Have you tried installing the missing libraries?

Comment: I followed this instruction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776053/opencv-gtk2-x-error and it worked. Dilanm, yes I tried but going through the `make` and `install` phase, is not an easy task always. My problem is now solved