# How to get OpenCV to work in nix?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, nix

I am trying to get an OpenCV hello world program to work using the nix package manager but its spewing out errors :

> OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /tmp/nix-build-opencv-2.4.13.drv-0/opencv-2.4.13-src/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 483
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what():  /tmp/nix-build-opencv-2.4.13.drv-0/opencv-2.4.13-src/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:483: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow

I used the following default.nix file to create a nix-shell

```
with import <nixpkgs> {}; {
  cimgEnv = stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "cimgdev";
  buildInputs = [ pkgconfig stdenv cimg xorg.libX11 boost opencv gnome.gtk ];
  }; 
}
```

to compile and run the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {

  Mat image;

  image = imread("lena.jpg", 1);

  if ( !image.data ) {
    cout << "No image data" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  imshow("Display Image", image);

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

using the following command

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` opencvtest.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o opencvtest
```

It compiles, but if I try to run it, I get the previous error message.

I tried CMake, with the same outcome.

Comment: I'm not familiar with nix, but the error message says `install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config` but you don't seem to be specifying `libgtk2.0-dev` anywhere. [See this answer too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30979195/1270789).

Comment: @KenY-N - I added "gnome.gtk" to my default.nix file, which I believe is the equivalent of libgtk2.0-dev in nix packages.

Answer (score 8):

OpenCV was built without GTK support. In the [opencv package definition](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/4f3446f29910d21eb0fb942bd03091b089cdad63/pkgs/development/libraries/opencv/default.nix#L4), `enableGtk2` defaults to `false`. To enable it, override the argument in your `default.nix`:

```
let
  opencvGtk = opencv.override (old : { enableGtk2 = true; });
in 
   ...
   buildInputs = [... opencvGtk ...];
   ...
```

There's no need to add `gtk2` nor anything besides `pkgconfig` to `buildInputs` unless you want to use it directly.
After the lengthy opencv rebuild, building and running the code above works (given `lena.jpg`):

[image: it works]

Comment: `$ cd /nix/store/` `$ ls | grep opencv` `$ cd ..opencv..` `$ find . -name "*.pc"` gives opencv4.pc so I needed $ g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv4` opencvtest.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv4` -o opencvtest

Answer (score 4):

I know that this question is for C++ but as this page is the first result in Google for people looking for the same problem with python, I think it can be useful to provide the solution for python as well…

So here is a shell.nix sample (replace python37 with the version of your choice)  :

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
pkgs.mkShell {
  name = "dev-shell";
  buildInputs = [
    pkgs.python37Packages.numpy
    pkgs.python37Packages.flask
    # …
    (pkgs.python37Packages.opencv4.override { enableGtk2 = true; })
  ];
}
```

Or in a less verbose way :

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
pkgs.mkShell {
  name = "dev-shell";
  buildInputs = with pkgs.python37Packages; [
    numpy
    flask
    # …
    (opencv4.override { enableGtk2 = true; })
  ];
}
```

EDIT 2023-02-09

Actually, the right way seems to be :

```
{pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}}:

pkgs.mkShell {
  name = "dev-shell";

  packages = [
    (pkgs.python38.withPackages(ps: [
      ps.numpy
      ps.flask
      (ps.opencv4.override {enableGtk2 = true;})
    ]))
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First glance at [this.](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html)

Seem like your OpenCV build lack of [UI support](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=namedwindow#namedwindow) for appropriate platform (mainly they are in highgui library). I get these things from OpenCV [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)

```
status("")
status("  GUI: ")

if(HAVE_QT5)
  status("    QT 5.x:"            HAVE_QT        THEN "YES (ver ${Qt5Core_VERSION_STRING})" ELSE NO)
  status("    QT OpenGL support:" HAVE_QT_OPENGL THEN "YES (${Qt5OpenGL_LIBRARIES} ${Qt5OpenGL_VERSION_STRING})" ELSE NO)
elseif(HAVE_QT)
  status("    QT 4.x:"            HAVE_QT        THEN "YES (ver ${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${QT_VERSION_MINOR}.${QT_VERSION_PATCH} ${QT_EDITION})" ELSE NO)
  status("    QT OpenGL support:" HAVE_QT_OPENGL THEN "YES (${QT_QTOPENGL_LIBRARY})" ELSE NO)
else()
  if(DEFINED WITH_QT)
    status("    QT:" NO)
  endif()
  if(DEFINED WITH_WIN32UI)
    status("    Win32 UI:" HAVE_WIN32UI THEN YES ELSE NO)
  else()
    if(APPLE)
      if(WITH_CARBON)
        status("    Carbon:" YES)
      else()
        status("    Cocoa:"  YES)
      endif()
    else()
      if(HAVE_GTK3)
        status("    GTK+ 3.x:" HAVE_GTK THEN "YES (ver ${ALIASOF_gtk+-3.0_VERSION})" ELSE NO)
      elseif(HAVE_GTK)
        status("    GTK+ 2.x:" HAVE_GTK THEN "YES (ver ${ALIASOF_gtk+-2.0_VERSION})" ELSE NO)
      else()
        status("    GTK+:" NO)
      endif()
      status("    GThread :" HAVE_GTHREAD THEN "YES (ver ${ALIASOF_gthread-2.0_VERSION})" ELSE NO)
      status("    GtkGlExt:" HAVE_GTKGLEXT THEN "YES (ver ${ALIASOF_gtkglext-1.0_VERSION})" ELSE NO)
    endif()
  endif()
endif()

status("    OpenGL support:" HAVE_OPENGL THEN "YES (${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})" ELSE NO)
status("    VTK support:" HAVE_VTK THEN "YES (ver ${VTK_VERSION})" ELSE NO)
```

You can see a lot of GUI support, including Gtk2 as stated. So install ibgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config as said. Make sure HAVE_GTK variable valid. After configure by CMake, by default the support of GTK will ON. Otherwise you can check it.

Please edit/comment if you see anything not right.

Comment: I added "gnome.gtk" to my default.nix file, which I believe is the equivalent of libgtk2.0-dev in nix packages. pkgconfig is also in there.