# OpenCv GTK error in Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, anaconda

I am doing this project where I need to show the next edited image in new window. I did editing with OpenCV. 

Now, I am using command `cv.imshow("result", image)` and I am getting this error. 
I tried [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776053/opencv-gtk2-x-error) but they didn't work. 

Apparantly, there is no `OpenCv` folder which contains `CmakeLists.txt` so that I can `cmake` `OpenCv` again. 

Please tell me **how can I `cmake` OpenCv in Anaconda?** or is there any other possible solution to that problem?

Peace.