# Build package with customized port file using vcpkg

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I installed `OpenCV` package using `vcpkg`, and since the `OpenCV` comes with `vcpkg`'s own build configuration does not support `libgtk`, I got error when trying to run `OpenCV` with in `WSL2` on windows 10. 
The solution I found [OpenCV GTK+2.x error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776053/opencv-gtk2-x-error) suggests to add `-DWITH_GTK=ON` to the `cmake` configuration. And I added that option to the portfile in `$vcpkgRoot/port/opencv4/porfile.make`. And I try to rebuild/update the `OpenCV`, but seems it does not work. 
I searched the documentation and could not find a clear description on how to use updated/customized portfile to rebuild the package. The only way that seems to work is to uninstall and install it again with the modified portfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `vcpkg install opencv` and then used `vcpkg remove opencv` opencv4 will not be removed since the port `opencv` is just a redirection to `opencv4`. So if you want to remove opencv4 you need to use `vcpkg remove opencv4 --recurse` or `vcpkg remove opencv opencv4`. The same is true for e.g. `openssl` which needs to specific the platform e.g `openssl-windows` for correct removal.

And you cannot use the `upgrade` command since this requires a change of the version in the CONTROL file.